# How to packagingExcludes css with regex if css is minified

Tags: java, regex, maven

```
<packagingExcludes>%regex[.*(\w)(?!=\.min)\.css]</packagingExcludes>
```

I need to exclude `xxx.css` if it has `xxx.min.css`, but this doesn't work.

> e.g. **main.css**, main.min.css, table.css, **main-14.css**, main-14.min.css.

Bold is equal to the current files selected.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I can get the filename `.*(\/)(?<filename>\S+)(?=.min)` in group *filename*. So, how can I do a global search with this filename and do this in one `%regex[...]` script?

Comment: Did you test your regex with [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)?

Comment: Are you trying to select every file ending in `.min.css`? If that's the case, you can use `\.min\.css$`

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I'm trying to check, css have minified or not? e.g. if i have main.css and main.min.css, select only main.css

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 e.x. **main.css**, main.min.css, table.css, **main-14.css**, main-14.min.css. Bold equal select

Comment: Do you need to check if there is already a `main.css` and only if there is one, omit the `main.min.css`? Otherwise you can just use `\.min\.css$` and exclude everything that matches this regex.

Comment: Here is an example: [example1](https://regex101.com/r/XZw5o9/1) You only need to look out if there is a match of that pattern in the filename. If you need a full match of the pattern over your filename, you can use `.*\.min\.css$` → [example2](https://regex101.com/r/XZw5o9/2)

Comment: I need to check if there is a minified file main.css with that name, delete the normal main.css and leave main.min.css. Also keep a simple file.css without minified